# Entity Framework 5.0 code-first with MySQL Connector 6.6.5.0 on .Net 4.5

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, .net-4.5, mysql-connector

For the life of me, I can't get my C# WinApp to work with Entity Framework 5.0 with a MySql database using MySql connector 6.6.5.0 (`MySql.Data` reference) and MySql Entity 6.5.4.0 (`MySql.Data.Entity` reference). Using .Net Framework 4.5 on Visual Studio 2012.  At the time of this writing, the versions above are all the latest stable ones.

Here's what I have on app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" 
           invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
           description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" 
           type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionName" 
         connectionString="Server=mysql13.myserver.com.br;Database=mydb;User Id=username;Pwd=pa$$w0rd;" 
         providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data">
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.6.5.0" newVersion="6.6.5.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

In the code

User class

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        Permissions = new List<Permission>();
    }
}

public class Permission
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
}
```

Creating a new record

```
        using (var db = new UserContext())
        {
            Permission permission1 = new Permission() { Name = "Permission 1", Description = "The desc 1" };
            Permission permission2 = new Permission() { Name = "2nd Perm", Description = "Desc2" };
            User user = new User() { Name = "Joao" };
            user.Permissions.Add(permission1);
            user.Permissions.Add(permission2);

            db.Users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

And I get the exception at the line `db.Users.Add(user);`

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Failed to set Database.DefaultConnectionFactory to an instance of the 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data' type as specified in the application configuration. See inner exception for details.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.<.ctor>b__1()
       at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.get_DefaultConnectionFactory()
       [removing the rest of the stack]
  InnerException: System.InvalidCastException
       HResult=-2147467262
       Message=Unable to cast object of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory' to type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbConnectionFactory'.
       Source=EntityFramework
       StackTrace:
            at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.<.ctor>b__1()
       InnerException:
```

I've tried several things, including adding `Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d` in the `DbProviderFactories` section to no avail..

I added the Entity Framework, MySql Data Connector and MySql.Data.Entity using NuGet Package Manager.

I've seen many other posts with a similar problem, but can't find a clear solution, especially with the versioning combo EF 5 + MySql Connector 6.6.5.0.

Has anyone made this work?  Can you post both the app.config AND the code to make it work?

Comment: Rename your connection string to be the same as your DbContext class. PS My personal advice. Don't use MySQL with EF. The implementation is broken.

Comment: Oh and remove the EntityFramework section.

Comment: Thanks Aron, I'll give this a shot. And you think the implementation is broken based on your experience? I'm thinking my app will have at most simple join queries, nothing too complicated.. still think it's best if I don't used EF with MySql?

Comment: Even "not very complicated" queries I have found to produce unexpected results. The worst of which is where it produces `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM foo) ORDER BY BAR`. Which MySQL does not optimize the query (at all) correctly.

Comment: If you need EF I would advise any database that isn't MySQL or SQLite.

Comment: Could you post your app.config file?   I think your tips are in the right direction, but now I'm getting a `System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data.Entity, Version=6.6.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.` My guess is that I'm messing up a reference to MySql.Data to where it should be MySql.Data.Entity or something, but can't put my finger on it..

Comment: Ah...sounds like you are almost there...What that error says is that it can find a copy of `MySQL.Data.Entity.dll`, but its the wrong version. Sounds like another version is in the GAC. Since `MySQL.Data.Entity` is only referenced via `MySQL.Data` there isn't a hard dependency to it. You will need to include that as well in your references. This class is used by EntityFramework to generate Linq queries against MySQL.

Answer (score 5):

The MySQL Connector 6.6.5 only supports Entity Framework 4.3 as mentioned [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/mysql_connector_net_6_65). I have personally used it which worked well so far. However, if you require Entity Framework 5 specifically, you would need to use MySQL Connector 6.6.7 Beta which now supports it as mentioned [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/mysql_connector_net_6_72). I haven't tried v 6.6.7 though.

Update 1: You can find the blog post of using EF 4.3 code-first with MySQL Connector 6.6 [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/upgrading_to_code_first_migrations).

Update 2: Sample .NET 4.5 console application using EF 4.3 and MySql Connector 6.6.5 [here](https://github.com/cubski/EFMySQL).

Comment: Doesn't matter. I am currently using EF 5 against the 6.6.4 connector (and having huge pains with it).

Comment: @Aron I believe 6.6.4 doesn't support EF5.

Comment: Again...I reiterate. I am currently using EF 5 with the MySQL 6.6.4 connector in a production environment.

Comment: My bad. May I ask how you're doing it?

Comment: Works out of the box. The only issue is that the Linq provider produces SQL that MySQL can't optimize.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there's some strange assembly resolution issues. Try deleting the `assemblyBinding` element in your config file and then run NuGet's `Add-BindingRedirect` command.

Answer (score 0):

Most of my production web.config. I've taken out all the company specific stuff...
Also this config was setup for MVC4/EF5/OData 5.2 with IIS compression. Pretty complicated stuff...most of it won't be required. But I figured you wanted my raw config for reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="EdgeService.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Config.Watch" value="True" />
    <add key="log4net.Config" value="EdgeService.log4net.config" />
    <add key="PullVersionPeriod" value="30000" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="12288" maxUrlLength="10999" maxQueryStringLength="2097151"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" />
  </system.web>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <clear />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description="ADO.Net driver for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="svc-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Windsor" />
    </modules>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxQueryString="100000" />
      </requestFiltering>
      <authentication>
        <!--C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config-->
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="true">
          <providers>
            <clear />
            <add value="Negotiate" />
          </providers>
        </windowsAuthentication>
      </authentication>
    </security>
    <httpCompression>
      <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" staticCompressionLevel="9" dynamicCompressionLevel="4" />
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="Application/*" />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/atom+xml;type=feed;charset=utf-8" />
      </dynamicTypes>
    </httpCompression>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="C5687FC88969C44D" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.6.4.0" newVersion="6.6.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data.Entity" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.6.4.0" newVersion="6.6.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Web" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.6.4.0" newVersion="6.6.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.4.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Spatial" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem in my first day of using mysql in EF. And I found your config is incorrect, and it should be

```
  <entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity">
</defaultConnectionFactory>
```

And make sure you use .net framework 4.5 and mysql connector lib for .net 4.5 as well for EF 5, since the connector for .net 4 supports only EF 4.4.